# Cipher suite choice on macOS on Apple Silicon

Tags: tls, email, macos, cipher-selection

I have a postfix mail server that accepts these cipher suites:

```
tls_high_cipherlist=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I noticed that when accessing this from macOS 12.3 with an Apple Silicon CPU over TLSv1.3 (i.e. client can choose suite), it selects the `ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` suite, even though it's listed after the AES suites. I'm just (idly) wondering why – does Apple Silicon not have AES hardware acceleration?

#### Update

Further to @foreverska's comment, I had thought that TLSv1.3 had reversed the older policy of only allowing the server to choose a cipher suite, however, it's apparently not quite like that. [I found a discussion](https://github.com/hakasenyang/openssl-patch/issues/9) which clarified things. It's not so much that TLSv1.3 allows for client choice, but that TLSv1.3 suites are considered equal weight, effectively letting the client choose from a shortlist. A TLSv1.3 client connecting to a 1.3 server should *only* select from 1.3 suites, even if they are listed after 1.2 suites. This is borne out by the Qualys SSL labs results on one of my own sites, which is served from nginx with server-side suite ordering enabled:

[image: Qualys cipher ordering results]

However, while that's good to know, why macOS would select ChaCha20 over AES if it has acceleration remains a mystery...

Further confirmation of client ordering of cipher suites in TLSv1.3 from [RFC8446's definition of ClientHello](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.1.2):

> cipher_suites:  A list of the symmetric cipher options supported by
> the client, specifically the record protection algorithm
> (including secret key length) and a hash to be used with HKDF, in
> descending order of client preference.

and in [ServerHello](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.1.3):

> cipher_suite:  The single cipher suite selected by the server from
> the list in ClientHello.cipher_suites.

So it appears that the concept of server-side cipher suite ordering doesn't exist at all within TLSv1.3.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has an AES engine as part of the `Secure Enclave` subsystem.  It provides:

> a boot ROM to establish a hardware root of trust, an AES engine for efficient and secure cryptographic operations, and protected memory

> The AES Engine is a separate component from both the Secure Enclave and the Secure Enclave AES Engine, but its operation is closely tied to the Secure Enclave

The `Secure Enclave` hardware feature is listed in the reference to be on Mac computers with Apple silicon (and a several other Apple devices).

I couldn't find any definitive reason why an Apple silicon device would choose `Chacha20` over `AES`.  The link below provides speculation but nothing definitive.

**References**
[Apple Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-enclave-sec59b0b31ff/web)
[What's the appeal of using Chacha20 instead of AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/whats-the-appeal-of-using-chacha20-instead-of-aes)

Answer (score 0):

Which cipher suite is chosen by the server, irrespective of what accelerators a client has.  The client can submit a preference list, but the server is free to ignore it.

The key would be to check the postfix server's preference list.  If Chacha happens to be high on it's list (maybe it's in a VM without accelerator support), that may just be what it chooses.

Comment: I included the server's suite list in my question, but the server doesn't necessarily get to choose the suite because with TLSv1.3 (unlike 1.2 and below), all choices are good, and it's preferable to have the client choose in those circumstances.

Comment: I can't find reference to the idea that the client chooses which suite from the list to use.  Do you have a reference for this?  The client of course could submit a preference list which doesn't include cipher suites which would be too slow for them but the server ultimately selects from that list (to my current knowledge).

Comment: See update to my Q about that

Comment: Can you explain this "why macOS would select" line?  We now know the final ciphersuite is chosen by the server.  So I'm a bit confused why this line persists.  Did your macbook send a preferred ciphersuite list which only contains chacha or something?

Comment: No we don't know that. The upshot of that update is that *there is no server order for TLSv1.3 suites*, and it is up to the client after all. The server order policy appears to simply not apply to 1.3 suites. I tested it by removing ChaCha20 from the server's list, and the client was then happy to pick an AES suite, so it's not that the client lacks support but that it appears to actively prefer ChaCha20, hence my question - why?

Comment: Okay, my bad, so I've yet to convince you that the server chooses the cipher suite.  By removing chacha from the server the server didn't choose chacha and the server happily chose aes.  If you removed chacha from the client it would submit a preference list that doesn't include chacha and the server would happly choose AES.  The client does not choose it's own ciphersuite.
https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/tls-1-3-handshake-tls-1-2/

Comment: What? No! When the client and server *both* offer ChaCha20 and AES with TLSv1.3, the M1 Mac is choosing ChaCha20, while my own Intel Mac connecting to the same server, with the same OS, same client, same cipher suites, gets AES. If the server was choosing, it would be consistently one or the other.

Comment: "In reply to the “Client Hello” message, the server replies with the key agreement protocol that it has chosen. " - That link I just gave you.  Why it is different between your two macs may come down to them submitting differently ordered preference lists and the server honoring them.  That's a whole other question compared to "why does my M1 choose a chipher suite" to which the answer is "it doesn't".

Comment: Er, you just described exactly what client cipher suite ordering is!

Comment: So the question is, "Why does my M1 order chacha over aes in a TLS1.3 preference list?"  That's not the same as choosing.  The server is free to ignore preference and chose whatever it wants.  Why does the M1 order the way it does?  Because someone told it to.  Maybe the AES accelerator is a finite resource and compute time for ChaCha is less finite so that's how it was ordered.